# How to make Jenkins use maven builds cache for different workspaces?

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build docker images, but it is taking so long because I'm doing everything in the Dockerfile.

With the purpose of increasing its speed, I'm trying to build some dependencies with maven, store them in cache, and then packaging everything in one single jar so in Dockerfile I only have to copy it, e.g.:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker run -v ${PWD}/${image}/.jm2/repository:/root/.m2/repository -w /usr/src/mymaven -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/mymaven --rm maven:3-jdk-11 mvn install -f api/pom.xml -Dmaven.test.skip=true
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker run -v ${PWD}/${image}/.jm2/repository:/root/.m2/repository -w /usr/src/mymaven -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/mymaven --rm maven:3-jdk-11 mvn install -f api-2/pom.xml -Dmaven.test.skip=true
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker run -v ${PWD}/${image}/.jm2/repository:/root/.m2/repository -w /usr/src/mymaven -v ${PWD}/${image}/api-3:/usr/src/mymaven --rm maven:3-jdk-11 mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t image:tag
```

Note: .jm2 is a directory I'm created, something like ".jenkinsm2"

This works perfectly fine in my machine and it also seemed to work well when I ran the 1st try at Jenkins, but then I started it a 2nd time, and instead of using the local maven files already created from the 1st run (there were no changes), it started to download everything again. 
Then I noticed it was running in the same slave, but from a different workspace:

1. 1st run: workspace
2. 2nd run: workspace@2

Can this be the issue? How can I solve my problem?

Comment: https://plugins.jenkins.io/jobcacher/